# ASP.NET MVC web site template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to download ASP.NET MVC web site template. Please guide me where can i find and how i can use. I'm new to this pattern. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410597.aspx
it already starts with a little code and design to show you the basics then walks you through a few more things like how controllers work, how a model can be used to simplify dealing with posted values and common content etc.

Comment: Ouch, MSDN to learn new concepts? :P  Just kidding, good resource.

Comment: Too true. Depends on your skill level I guess. Some people can read them and make the most of it. I'm more into reverse engineering from something someone else has done, but learning that was is only as good as the code you start to reverse engineer from.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/  - design templates

http://www.asp.net/mvc  - look @ the sample application section (open source, good tutorials included)

Answer (score 0):

Guys from http://pixelsinspired.com are starting something you may be interested in. There is only one template, but it is free and looks great.